# Saving CTCoreMesssage from MailCore

Tags: ios, email, mailcore

I'm trying to come up with a way to store a local copy of the most recent emails from MailCore's CTCoreMessage so the user can view them locally offline. How would I go about doing this? I've looked into NSCoding but I don't want to rewrite most of MailCore to support it. What are some alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think here is the Solution to your problem.. Have you seen the remail, It is an open source application based on Mailcore in Which local store is creating in the form of SQlite database and .edb files are formed in your Document Directory. As I have done in my application After creation of the Connection with the server all mails are written locally and can work in the offline mode. You can get it from here..

http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/

For any other assistance related to it,.. ask from me..

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to retrive mails by specific date via MailCore framework ?

Comment: Your specific data means you did not want to retrieve all mails.. only particular mails that contains your specific data.. ? OR You can retrieve all mails and found where your specific data is..

Comment: I wrote specific Date's data.... suppose I want mails of today only not all mails...

Comment: Sorry, If I earlier interpreted wrongly.. No there is no specific direct method to fetch the mails of Specific date. But you can get the mails by passing the Index of the mails, after getting the complete headers of the mails.. you can compare its date.. and can show the specific one..

Comment: it will take too much load on network and device... says there are 3000 mails then....